# SQL DB2 null calculation causing problems

Tags: sql, null, db2, coalesce, isnull

I have the following SQL:

```
Select dmvndn "Vendor Number", IFNULL(sum(dmsls) / sum(dmprc), 0) "Calculation"
From MyFile
Group By dmvndn
```

However, when i run this, i am still getting null records in my "Calculation" field.

I have also tried the COALESCE function, which returns the same results.  I get some records as 0, and some records are blank (or, null).

Both fields are of type P, which i am told is packed numeric.

any ideas or suggestions?

**Edit 1**
It seems that the problem is not with either of these fields being NULL, it is that one or both fields are 0.  And when i divide by zero, i get the empty / blank result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick of this kind helps me in MS SQL Server:

```
Select
  dmvndn "Vendor Number",
  IFNULL(sum(dmsls) / NULLIF(sum(dmprc), 0), 0) "Calculation"
From MyFile
Group By dmvndn
```

I wonder if it can't help you in DB2.

**UPDATE:** an explanation.

Basically, it replaces the divisor with NULL if it's 0. And you may probably know that when at least one of the operands is NULL, the result of the operation becomes NULL as well.

To account for the result being NULL you already had your IFNULL on the result. It didn't make much difference *then*, because none of the operands was likely to be NULL. However, now using IFNULL makes perfect sense.

Comment: That did it! i tried so many combinations of this, and am still trying to figure out how this was different... but it works! lol. thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe my attempt at an explanation will help you to see the difference (added it to the answer).

Comment: oh wow... that completeley twisted my thought process around.  Change the zero to null, and if null then 0... lol.  nice job!  thanks for the explination too =]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Sum(IFNULL(dmsls,0)) / Sum(IFNULL(dmprc,0))
```

Comment: after reviewing the data, it seems that dmsls is already 0, and dmprc is already 0 as well.  dividing my zero is what is giving me this blank space. so this still gave me the same result =[